# Windows Explorer connect to webdav but require authorization

Tags: sql, authentication, webdav, explorer

I have a problem where I can't seem to find any solution.

I have a web application which uses webdav so I can connect to it via windows explorer and edit files. This works.

Now I want to use **authentication** with this folder. I already did this via a servlet filter with *BASIC Authentication* and *DIGEST Authentication* which both work fine, when the password is at some point available in cleartext.

The problem is that my **passwords** are stored in a **hashed format** in my sql database.

With **BASIC Authentication** i can compare the user pass with the database because it is transmitted in **cleartext**. **I don't want that**.
When I use DIGEST Authentification the pasword is transmitted in encrypted format and the password is needed in cleartext from the database to calculate the response. Since the password is already hashed there is no way to calculate a valid response.

I **also checked Negotiate/Spnego/ntlm** authorization but as far as I understand these are for windows users only and don't have anything to do with my sql database.
The database is either mysql, mssql or postgre.

Are there **any other** authentication mechanisms that work with **windows explorer**, where I can make it at least a little bit harder to decrypt the password so it won't be sent in cleartext?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is Forms Authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.ASPX